# Getting two consecutive $6$'s

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A standard six-sided die is rolled until two consecutive 6s appear. Find the expected number of rolls. Please see that this is a language problem. What do they mean by expected number of rolls? Should the answer be 36? Or 42?

Comment: Expected value: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: In short, average.

Comment: The answer will be 42.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be the expected number of rolls.   This is the mean number of roll we expect to take to witness the event.

To obtain two consecutive sixes, you must roll until you get a six followed immediately by a six (obviously).

Let the expected number of rolls until you get one six be : $F$.  Can you find what $F$ is?  (Hint: Geometric Distribution)

Then you will either get a six on the next roll (the seventh), or you don't and have to start all over from there.   There is a $5/6$ chance you don't, so we have a recursive definition for the expected number: $$E = F + 1 + \frac 5 6 E$$

Comment: Is there a way to give a rigourous explanation to your argument? Let me be more explicit: How do you justify that the original random variable $X$ that describes the number of die rolls until two consecutive $6$ is equal to a geometric distributed random variable $Y$ plus another random variable $Z$ that is similar to the original one $X$?

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of the number of rolls is defined as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot p_k
$$
where $p_k$ is the probability that it will take exactly $k$ rolls to make 2 consecutive 6's appear. This is what they mean, but using the definition directly may not be the best way to do this problem.